# C++ Challenge: Maximum unique reserved words in one logical line of code?

Tags: c++, puzzle, reserved-words

I have a perennial thought experiment about how to write a line of C++ code that has the maximum number of unique reserved words in it.  In this challenge, you can duplicate keywords as much as you'd like, but all that matters is the number of unique keywords you use.  For example, if you write

```
void MyFunction(int, int, int, int);
```

There are four instances of int, but the above line has a score of 2 because it only has two unique keywords in it (`void` and `int`, namely).  This line, though,

```
void MyFunction(int, double, short, long);
```

Has a score of 5 for its five reserved words.

So far, the best I've been able to come up with is

```
export template <typename T, class C>
inline void DiabolicalFunc (int, char, short, 
                            long, double, signed, 
                            unsigned, bool, float,
                            wchar_t, const int,
                            volatile int, 
                            enum MyEnum,
                            void* (*)(size_t) = &(operator new), 
                            void (*)(void*) = &(operator delete), 
                            int = const_cast<int*>(static_cast<const int *>(reinterpret_cast<int*>(0))), 
                            void* = dynamic_cast<void*>(reinterpret_cast<ios_base*>(0)),
                            bool = true, bool = false, int = sizeof(int), 
                            const std::type_info& = typeid(int),
                            struct MyStruct = MyStruct(), union MyUnion = MyUnion(), 
                            int = 0 and 0,
                            int = 0 bitand 0,
                            int = 0 bitor 0, 
                            int = compl 0, 
                            int = not 0, 
                            int = 0 not_eq 0,
                            int = 0 or 0, 
                            int = 0 xor 0) throw();
```

This has a whopping 39 reserved words in it.  It assumes that you have defined an `enum MyEnum`, `struct MyStruct`, and `union MyUnion` before declaring it, though.  And yes, this *does* compile in `g++` if you set up the appropriate types before using it (though it does give a warning about `export`.)

I'm curious if anyone sees any way to cram even more unique keywords into a line of code.  Can someone top my example?  Or find a way to make it Even More Diabolical?

I know that C++ is freeform so a "line of code" is not a really good measure of structure, but I think we can come to a reasonable interpretation of what this means.

**EDIT:** Just added `throw()` to the end of the function to get one more keyword in there.

Comment: Note that C++03 has 74 unique reserved names (ISO 14882:2003 C++ Standard 2.11/1 and 2.11/2). C++0x would have a few more reserved keywords.

Comment: By the way, [only moderators can CW-ize posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183).

Comment: "line of code... reasonable interpretation" - is going to have to include the function body if you're going to use break, continue, for, while etc..  But maybe it's more in spirit to restrict this to single declarations?

Comment: Somehow I prefer code-golfs, it seems harder to be concise :)

Answer (score 10):

A line of C++ code you say?

```
// asm auto bool break case catch char class const ...
```

I kid, I kid.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow for C++0x, you could return the `decltype` of the sum of an object of type T and C.

Comment: Hmmm... With C++0x you could also use `auto` for the function signature (`auto f (...) -> decltype(...)`).  You could also add in `constexpr`, the `alignof` operator, the `noexcept` keyword, and the `nullptr` constant.  That's a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

if you add a body to the function you can add some `register` and `auto` variables, a `try {} catch() {}` block, a `switch` with a `break` and a `return` and almost all other [C++ keywords](http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_keywords.html)
This is really an exercise in futility.

Comment: @shoosh- I'm not sure if that would qualify any more as "one logical line of code," though you definitely have a point.

Comment: If by "logical" you mean something any sane person would write, your example fails that as well.

Comment: If by "one logical line of code" you mean "a string of characters without any newlines in it," then a function with a body is possible. :-)

Comment: I'd guess that he means only one semi-colon?